# Images stretched in flex container but cannot use align-self-center

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have the following markup (Bootstrap 4):

```
<div class="col-3 d-flex flex-column">
    <img class="align-self-center" src="#"/>
</div>
```

Since the container is flexed, the images are stretching. I'm aware `align-self-center` will resolve the issue, however, I don't want the image to be centered. I want the image to be `align-self-left` (left aligned rather than centered), but this stretched the image again.

Any way around this?

Comment: add your image parent not needed any class in image <div class="col-3 d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go!

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-3 d-flex flex-column">
    <img class="align-self-start" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be `align-self-start`. Bootstrap flex doesn't use term `left`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using  `<img class="align-self-center" src="#"/>` use `<img class="align-self-start" src="#"/>`. This should solve your problem (Basically it means that you image will be aligned to the start of your column)